# installing SQL Server 2008 on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 on a Windows 7 64-bit machine.

I have a message telling me that this program is not compatible with my windows version and I have to install .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 for 64-bit.

I have downloaded it from internet but also I can't install it.

How can this be solved?

Comment: ensure you post screenshots or actual error messages to help troubleshoot in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these steps to ensure your installation of SQL Server 2008 goes smoothly.

- Install the [latest .NET Framework (4.0 at the moment)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en). Ensure that the installer you have supports your platform (i.e. both x86 and x64).
- Reboot as needed.
- Install SQL Server 2008 x64 (yes, there are different builds).
- Install SQL Server 2008 service packs.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.p.campbell, but I have a small question , for non 64-bit program, when I try to install it it creates x86 folder and install correctly in it , so why SQL 2008 don't do that also ?

Comment: @Amira: the mysteries of 'Program Files'. I wouldn't worry about it too much. Perhaps there are some reasons that SQL Server needs 'Program Files (x86)'. Likely those are compiled for 32 bit, and it runs under WoW64.  Don't worry about it. An installation of SQL Server x64 uses BOTH locations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded a 32-bit version of SQL Server? Get a 64 bit one!

Comment: a friend of mine told me that, there is no SQL 32-bit and SQL 64-bit , it is all based on the framework , I don't know if that is true or false , but when I search for 64-bit SQL i didn't find a lot of results

Comment: There are 3 versions: x86, x64, IA64 - make sure you install proper one.

Comment: @Amira Elsayed: this is rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have IA64 SQL Server instead of x64?

Comment: I don't know what is that, if you please explain more what is IA64 and why should I use it I will be thankful